# Access 2010 web compatibility error: ACCWeb107019

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

We are setting up a database in Access 2010 and we have encountered this problem.
Some of our tables are not qualified for the web, only some tables pass the Check Web Compatibility test.

We receive following web compatibility issues

```
error code: ACCWeb107019
error message: Property value should be set to 'Yes' to be compatible with the Web.
```

Question: How do we make those tables compatible with the web.

We have just created a blank database, not a web database, but as mentioned some of our tables do qualify for the web while others don't, we would like them all to qualify for the web, because it is possible to get a relationship overview and design view in the blank database, which we cant get in the web database templates

we hope someone out there can help us out :)

Answer (score 0):

Look-ups in tables are almost never a good idea, but sharepoint may require them. Do not do this unless you are sure you are moving to sharepoint.

From: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/web-compatibility-check-schema-errors-HA010377945.aspx#_Toc254722333

> ACCWeb107019
>
> Error text    Property value should be set to 'yes' to be compatible
>   with the Web.
>
> What it means    The Limit To List property of the indicated lookup
>   field is set to No, but the lookup field is not a single-valued value
>   list, and the property setting is therefore not compatible with the
>   Web.
>
> What to do    Use the Lookup Wizard to modify the lookup field. Make
>   sure you select the Limit to List checkbox when the wizard displays
>   it.